# Merge dataframes but keep common column

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames using two common columns using the following code.

```
data = merge(df1, df2,by.x=c("b_id"), by.y=c("e_id"), all=T)
```

This works fine. BUT there are some rows (cases of data) which have an ID and data for the second data frame, and not the first (and vice versa). This means I return lines of NA for the first data frame (or vice versa).

I am wondering how I could return a merged data set where the second data frames ID number is appended to the first data frames ID number in the merged data frame. In programmes like SPSS or STATA it does this automatically if you merge two data sets with differing completeness of data.

e.g. I want to return this.

```
    b_id  dfv1  dfv2
    1101    5   NA
    1102    5   5
    1103    8   9
    1104    NA  3
    1105    NA  12
```

Not this!

```
    b_id  dfv1 dfv2
    1101    5   NA
    1102    5   5
    1103    8   9
    NA      NA  3
    NA      NA  12
```

From these two dataframes:

```
    b_id  dfv1              
    1101    5               
    1102    5               
    1103    8               
    NA      NA              
    NA      NA              

    e_id    dfv2              
    NA      NA              
    1102    5               
    1103    9               
    1104    3               
    1105    12
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example (using sample data) of how you want the merge to be done? (I don't know STATA/SPSS merge functions and I'm not sure I understand what you mean)

Comment: What is the input (df1 and df2) for the desired output you included in your question?

Comment: Input in the example in my question is df1 which hypothetically has two columns 1 a column of data (dfv1) and 1 a column with a unique id number (b_id). For data frame 2 there is 1 column of data (dfv2) and 1 column with a unique id number (e_id) which gets dropped when you merge.

Comment: It is very good that you add the desired output, but why don't you just also include the input for the small example? This would make answering much easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input data is not provided, it is kind of hard to be sure about what is asked for. Based on what I understand from the question, the input *could* look like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(b_id = c(1101, 1102, 1103), dfv1 = c(5,5,8))
df2 <- data.frame(e_id = c(1102, 1103,1104,1105), dfv2 = c(5,9,3,12))

> df1
  b_id dfv1
1 1101    5
2 1102    5
3 1103    8

> df2
  e_id dfv2
1 1102    5
2 1103    9
3 1104    3
4 1105   12
```

Now, if you run

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "b_id", by.y = "e_id", all = TRUE)

  b_id dfv1 dfv2
1 1101    5   NA
2 1102    5    5
3 1103    8    9
4 1104   NA    3
5 1105   NA   12
```

Does this answer the question? If not, please edit your question to include the input data.

#### Update

With the input data provided, it is now possible to answer your question. This seems to produce what you are looking for with the input data you provided:

```
merge(df1[complete.cases(df1),], df2[complete.cases(df2),], by.x = "b_id", by.y = "e_id", all = T)

  b_id dfv1 dfv2
1 1101    5   NA
2 1102    5    5
3 1103    8    9
4 1104   NA    3
5 1105   NA   12
```

So basically you exclude all rows that are not complete in each data.frame and the merge the two (which creates some new NA as in your desired output).

Comment: Thanks beginneR. Your code looks exactly the same as the one I've tried, which returns the 'Not this' example in my question. I want to be able to carry over the e_id to merge with b_id if there is NA for b_id and dfv1, but data for e_id and dfv2.

Comment: Thanks beginneR. It doesn't quite do it unfortunately, still returns NA's in the b_id column. Thank you so much for trying to find a solution. Think I might try another program now...

Comment: You failed to provide an accurate example of your problem then, since it works for the sample data without problems. It should be impossible to return `NA`s in the `b_id` column if you used `complete.cases` correctly. Perhaps you should check your data before that `merge` to see if you have some funny entries in there (like "NA").

Comment: Aha! Thanks. There was one funny entry out of around 2.5k. Removed that and it works. Many thanks!